# How i can insensitive accent an capital letters in agregattion?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, accent-sensitive

I want to make a query that does not discriminate by accents or upper or lower case, i have this:

```
query && pipeline.unshift({
  '$match': { 'name': { '$regex': new RegExp(query, 'i') } }
})
```

I tried a lot of regex but i don't know how i can use it, can you help me, please

Answer (score 0):

- `$regex` add `$options` : `i`, case insensitivity to match upper and lower cases.

```
db.collection.find({
  name: {
    $regex: "sam",
    $options: "i"
  }
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_ntA2DLuo1a)

Comment: yes, but this only works with with upper case and lower case, not for insensitivity of accents :(